Update .NET *.csproj PackageReference from float versioning to strict one (like 1.* -> 1.0.4)
I've got a kind of 'rolling update' policy for nugets:
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.*" />
...
</ItemGroup>

In addition, I have packages.lock.json with specific versions.
Now the release time comes.
I will cut the release branch and I need to 'freeze' nuget versions for a month in a release branch.
Question: can I do some magic trick and set specific strict version of the nuget package for release branch, something like:
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.*" /> + packages.lock.json + some command -> <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.4" />


Note: <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.4" /> is not a strict version rule; that would be Version="[12.0.4]"

Do you mean you want use some command to update PackageReference  from float version to strict one  instead of manually modifying ?

@DouXu-MSFT yes if this is possible.

Hi @SergeyShafiev,  did you try Package Manager Console commands to achieve it?

If you want  update .csproj PackageReference from float version to strict one via some command, you can use Package Manager Console commands to achieve it.
Update-Package  AutoMapper -Version 13.0.1

After running above command, it will automatically update the following files:
project file
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.4" />
</ItemGroup>

packages.lock.json file
 "AutoMapper": {
        "type": "Direct",
        "requested": "[12.0.4, )",
        "resolved": "12.0.4"
  }

Docs Referred:
Update-Package (Package Manager Console in Visual Studio)
